# SSL Configuration for a Web Service - I am getting address mismatch error also not able to open the intranet site using chrome

Tags: asp.net, ssl, service

I have hosted a web service Windows 2019 IIS 10.0.
Created a self-signed certificate and created the binding.

But I am getting the address mismatch error also when I am trying to open the link using chrome (on the server) it is not opening.
Please help.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jk541.png)

Error in IE:Error Code: DLG_FLAGS_SEC_CERT_CN_INVALID
But it is still opening with a certificate error.

Error in Chrome: ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your hostname is in one of those fields - *not* in the friendly name, which doesn't play a part.

IE has more permissive certificate handling than Chrome.  I had a misconfigured certificate where the hostname wasn't in the subject or SANs and got the same errors.